# ErrorException Array to string conversion Laravel 8

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have JSON-formed data and it is converted into the array.
But I cannot iterate the array and fetch the data, it shows an error.

> ErrorException Array to string conversion

**Data:**

```
Array
(
    [posts] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [post_id] => 5083755625086176
                    [text] => Carry on the Trend!
                    [links] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [link] => https:// .........
                                    [text] => xyz
                                )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [link] => https:// .........
                                [text] => xyz
                            )
                         )
                )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [post_id] => 5083755138419558
                [text] => Carry on the Trend!
                [links] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [link] => https:// .........
                                [text] => xyz
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [link] => https:// .........
                                [text] => xyz
                            )
                      )
             )

        [2] => .........
            
      )
)
```

**Controller**

```
foreach($array['posts'] as $scrapeData){
        $product = new Product;
        $product->id= $scrapeData['post_id'];
        $product->description = $scrapeData['text'];

        $product->save();
    }

    foreach($array['posts']['links'] as $datalink){
        $images_links = new ProductImage;
        $images_links->link= $datalink['link'];
       
        $images_links->save();
    }
```

Comment: maybe it already becomes clearer if you fix the indentation/formatting of the array. You have a 2-dimensional array and need to loop through the outer one (posts) and within in each through the inner one (links)

Answer (score 3):

You have to move your second loop into the first to iterate the `links`:

```
     foreach($array['posts'] as $scrapeData){
        $product = new Product;
        $product->id= $scrapeData['post_id'];
        $product->description = $scrapeData['text'];
        $product->save();

        foreach($scrapeData['links'] as $datalink) {
            $images_links = new ProductImage;
            $images_links->link= $datalink['link'];
            $images_links->save();
        }
    }
```